# Python - Divide each row by a vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 10x10 matrix and I want to divide each row of the matrix with the elements of a vector.

For eg:
Suppose I have a 3x3 matrix

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

and a vector `[1, 2, 3]`

Then this is the operation I wish to do:

```
1/1 1/2 1/3
2/1 2/1 2/3
3/1 3/2 3/3
```

i.e, divide the elements of a row by the elements of a vector(A python list)

I can do this using for loops. But, is there a better way to do this operation in python?

Comment: I suppose by matrix and vector you mean numpy arrays?

Comment: A numpy matrix and a python list as a vector.

Comment: If `a` is your array and `v` is your list then use `a/np.array(v)`. I downvoted the question because you did not seem to have tried anything.

Comment: And I upvoted, because it is a useful question and complete as stated.   Moreover he did say what he tried, "for loops".  And, it is okay that he does not know that there is something else to try, i.e. broadcasting, else he would not have needed to ask.  So the question is fine, I am glad he asked.   (BTW, should the element at 2,2 be 2/2 rather than 2/1?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into broadcasting in numpy. For your example this is the solution:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3]).reshape(1, 3)
c = a / b 
print(c)
>>> [[1.         0.5        0.33333333]
     [2.         1.         0.66666667]
     [3.         1.5        1.        ]]
```

Comment: Reshaping does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: in this case apparently not, just checked. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

The first source array should be created as a *Numpy* array:

```
a = np.array([
    [ 1, 1, 1 ],
    [ 2, 2, 2 ],
    [ 3, 3, 3 ]])
```

You don't need to reshape the divisor array (it can be a **1-D** array,
as in your source data sample):

```
v = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

Just divide them:

```
result = a / v
```

and the result is:

```
array([[1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333],
       [2.        , 1.        , 0.66666667],
       [3.        , 1.5       , 1.        ]])
```